# Tooltip window changing height and width when more text is added

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, html-table

i tried to make this tooltip dynamic with the text (so when there is less text - smaller window) but it didn't work for me. I need this tooltip to change size of itself when more text is added and shrink itself when there is only a few words. Example in Jsfiddle.

PS: I don't like to use JS, but if it's necessary I can live with that.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d4m5hj6f/

```css
.content {
  position: static;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

th, td { 
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  background-color: #eff0f0;
}

td {
  background-color: #eed6b1;
  height: 45px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #FFF1E1;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  min-width: 2000px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.DZ {
  text-align: center;
}


tr:hover td {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

tr td {
  border-right: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
}

.Bezborder {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.ht:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip {
  position:absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #fafbb8;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 28px;
  padding: 10px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 680px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="header">
  </div>

  <a name="172016">
    <!--1. riadok H-->
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <th width="50px">C. u.</th>
        <th width="30px">Zobrazit</th>
        <th width="30px">Typ</th>
        <th width="220px">Look here ---></th>
        <th width="650px">hover Under this</th>
        <th width="130px">System</th>
        <th width="100px">Dopad/Symptom</th>
        <th width="100px">Dátum zadania</th>
        <th width="100px">Dátum vzniku</th>
        <th width="100px">Datum Verifikacie</th>
        <th width="80px">Ukoncenie</th>
        <th width="100px">Dátum</th>
      </tr>
      <!--2. riadok D-->
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center">100</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">X</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">C </td>
        <td>DOBRIKOVA/DURACKA</td>
        <td class="ht"> Gefco PC nasa siet CD vs finalne riesenie internet gefco pc CORAIL <span class="tooltip">Tooltip windows need to change with text, more text - larger window, less text = smaller windows.</span></td>  
        <td>CORAIL/CONSO</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
        <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
        <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">OK</td>
        <td class="Bezborder" style="text-align:center">07/07/2016</td>
      </tr>
      <!--3. riadok D-->
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center">101</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">X</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">C </td>
        <td>DOBRIKOVA/DURACKOVA</td>
        <td class="ht"> Gefco PC nasa siet CD vs finalne riesenie internet gefco pc CORAIL <span class="tooltip">You see there is a big tooltip window space under this.</span></td>
        <td>CORAIL/CONSO</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
        <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
        <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">OK</td>
        <td class="Bezborder" style="text-align:center">07/07/2016</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the width property from the tooltip css should work. Remove the height too if you want it to adapt when resizing the window.

Comment: I feel sooo stupid right now, this is exactly I needed. I added max-weight: 680px and its working how I wanted. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieved something like this

```css
.content {
position: static;
}

.header {
text-align: center;
position: relative;
margin-top: 40px;
}


th, td{
 border:1px solid black;
 overflow: hidden;
}

th{
background-color: #eff0f0;
}

td{
background-color: #eed6b1;
height: 45px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
background-color: #FFF1E1;
}

table{
table-layout: fixed;
min-width: 2000px;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
margin-left: 5px;
}

.DZ {
text-align: center;
}


tr:hover td{
background-color: #ccc;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

tr td{
border-right: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
}

.Bezborder {
border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.ht:hover .tooltip {
display: block;
}

.tooltip {
position:absolute;
display: none;
background-color: #fafbb8;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-left: 28px;
padding: 10px;
position:absolute;
z-index: 1000;
width: 680px;
/* height: 50px;*/
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
  <div class="content">
  <div class="header">
  </div>

 <a name="172016">
   <!--1. riadok H-->
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <tr>
 <th width="50px">C. u.</th>
 <th width="30px">Zobrazit</th>
 <th width="30px">Typ</th>
 <th width="220px">Cislo/Meno</th>
 <th width="650px">Popis</th>
 <th width="130px">System</th>
 <th width="100px">Dopad/Symptom</th>
 <th width="100px">Dátum zadania</th>
 <th width="100px">Dátum vzniku</th>
 <th width="100px">Datum Verifikacie</th>
 <th width="80px">Ukoncenie</th>
 <th width="100px">Dátum</th>
</tr>
<!--2. riadok D-->
<tr>
 <td style="text-align:center">100</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">X</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">C </td>
 <td>DOBRIKOVA/DURACKA</td>
 <td class="ht"> Gefco PC nasa siet CD vs finalne riesenie internet gefco pc CORAIL <span class="tooltip">ked sa vytvara uplne novu hypotheza tak nefunguje vyber tlaciarni a globalny export tiez NOK (nepouzivame)</span></td>     
 <td>CORAIL/CONSO</td>
 <td></td>
 <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
 <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
 <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">OK</td>
 <td class="Bezborder" style="text-align:center">07/07/2016</td>
</tr>
<!--3. riadok D-->
<tr>
 <td style="text-align:center">101</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">X</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">C </td>
 <td>DOBRIKOVA/DURACKOVA</td>
 <td class="ht"> Gefco PC nasa siet CD vs finalne riesenie internet gefco pc CORAIL <span class="tooltip">ked sa vytvara uplne novu hypotheza tak nefunguje vyber tlaciarni a globalny export tiez NOK (nepouzivame)</span></td>
 <td>CORAIL/CONSO</td>
 <td></td>
 <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
 <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
 <td class="DZ">06/07/2016</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">OK</td>
 <td class="Bezborder" style="text-align:center">07/07/2016</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is almost it! But there is a problem. Its on changing its height, not width. I need it to be max-width of 680px an after it reach this limit it will go to the next line. But now when you add short text like "hey" it will still be 680px.

Comment: put max-width:680px; to .tooltip class and remove width:680px; it will work

Comment: insted of width:680px; try max-width:680px; it is working

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have a fix value for your tooltip width and height.

If you need to make the toolip width and height adjusted dynamically by its content you should remove the `width` and `height` value.

Edit based on your comment.

If you need to keep some space between the tooltip and your view port you can use `margin` property, this will allow some space on each d side of your tooltip.

Try to comment out  as in the follow example:

https://jsfiddle.net/d4m5hj6f/6/

```
.tooltip {
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: #fafbb8;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 28px;
    padding: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    /*width: 680px;*/
    /*height: 50px;*/
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: When you make your browser smaller, text will leave the tooltip window. I need that text to stay in that window